# How can FileNotFoundException occur during createNewFile() in this case?

Tags: java, android, file-io

Here is an attempt to write to external storage on my device:

```
private void extract(ZipInputStream zis) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry entry;
    while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if(!entry.isDirectory()) {
            writeFile(zis, entry.getName());
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
    }
    zis.close();
}

private void writeFile(ZipInputStream zis, String filename) {
    /* flag to determine if creation of every directory leading to
     * filename was successful */
    boolean newDirsSuccess;
       if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "decrompressed/" + filename);
            // ignore special files
if(newFile.getName().equals(".DS_Store")||newFile.getAbsolutePath().contains("__") ) {
                return;
            }

            File parentDir = newFile.getParentFile();
            // if the file's parent structure isn't there, create it
            if (!parentDir.exists()) {
                newDirsSuccess = parentDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // this line throws a FileNotFoundException NOENT
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            byte[] byteArr = new byte[4096];
            int numBytes = 0;

            // read from ZipInputStream and rite the bytes
            while((numBytes = zis.read(byteArr)) != -1) {
                bos.write(byteBuffer, 0, numBytes);
            }
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A FileNotFoundException is thrown when trying to create the FileOutputStream.  I want to see the value of newDirsSuccess, but it does not show up in the debugger window so I'm not sure where this exception is coming from.

The "newFile" declaration should have created a new empty file, and parentDir.makeDirs() should have created any directories leading up to this new file, so why is this exception being thrown?

parentDir looked like: "/storage/emulated/0/decompressed/game1_stats"

Comment: Did `mkdirs()` return `true`?

Comment: did you read the question?

Comment: Yes, I did read the question, and I didn't see the answer there. I still don't. The answer is still required, notwithstanding your failure to produce it. You could *print* the result for example, or assign it to a variable in a larger scope. I am also wondering why your title says the exception happens in `createNewFile()` when you aren't calling `createNewFile()` (and when `createNewFile()` doesn't throw exceptions, and would be redundant anyway). Questions containing and relying on this amount of guesswork can't be answered.

Comment: "I want to see the value of newDirsSuccess, but it does not show up in the debugger window so I'm not sure where this exception is coming from."

newDirsSuccess is said variable.  createNewFile was something I had until I realized it was redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lacked the permission to write to external storage.  Add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```